# How to send a string parameter from c# to powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing 2 apps one with c# and the other with powershell 1.0, in some point of my code I want to pass a string that indicating the server name from my c# app to a powershell script file that I wrote, how do I send it? and how do i accept it?

my code :

```
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
runspace.Open();
RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

String scriptfile = @"c:\test.ps1";

Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile, false);
CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("username", "serverName");

myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);


pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
Collection<PSObject> psObjects;
psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
```

and my powershell script

```
param([string]$Username)

write-host $username
```

What am I missing? I'm kinda new with powershell.

Comment: Try to remove everything from your powershell file except the "write-host $username" line

Comment: What happens when you run that?  Does the powershell script not run at all, or give the wrong output, or give no output at all, or ...?  If you run that powershell script directly from powershell does it work?

Comment: i found an answer it was this:  
  
Go to Start Menu and search for "Windows PowerShell ISE".

Right click the x86 version and choose "Run as administrator".

In the top part, paste Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned; run the script. Choose "Yes".  
  
but now i got a new problem. now i get:  
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.  
  
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have machines with PowerShell 2.0 and 3.0 but not 1.0, so my results may differ.  When I run your code on my PowerShell 3.0 box, I get:

> A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the
>   command type does not support user interaction. Try a host program
>   that supports user interaction, such as the Windows PowerShell Console
>   or Windows PowerShell ISE, and remove prompt-related commands from
>   command types that do not support user interaction, such as Windows
>   PowerShell workflows.

It didn't like the Write-Host, so I changed your script to

```
param([string]$Username)

Get-Date
Get-ChildItem -Path $userName
```

Get-Date so that I could see some output without depending on the parameter and GCI to use the parameter.  I modified your code to look like this:

```
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
{
    runspace.Open();

    String scriptfile = @"..\..\..\test.ps1";
    String path = @"C:\Users\Public\";

    var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.Add(new Command("Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process", true));
    pipeline.Invoke();

    pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    var myCommand = new Command(scriptfile, false);
    var testParam = new CommandParameter("username", path);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);
    pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
    var psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
    foreach (var obj in psObjects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
    }
    runspace.Close();
}

Console.WriteLine("Press a key to continue...");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

and it ran without error and displayed the folder contents, on both PoSh 2 and 3.

For info, if you're only setting the execution policy for the current process, you don't need to run elevated, hence I was able to do it in-code.